# React select rtl is not working for options

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I use isRtl as a prop with react select like this :

```
      <Select onChange={handleChange} isRtl isMulti options={colourOptions} />
```

But only the input gets rtl direction style and not the options .

How can I have rtl for both input and options with react select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem which was bootstrap styles . Bootstrap has a style for body which is `text-align : left;` so I had to override it like this in main styles component :

```
body {
  text-align : initial ;
}
```